# Hibernate not returning existing data

Tags: hibernate, sql-server-2005, model

I have a small java app that connects to a MS Sql Server database via Hibernate.

I have a table called user that has 3 colums, Username, password and email.

I have a model POJO called UserModel that has getters and setter for Username and password.

Using hibernate, my code does a 'find' on the database, passing in Username and password and to returning a UserModel object.

What I need:

I want to remove the need to pass the password into the query, e.g.

```
List<UserModel> UserModels = null;
    UserModel model = new UserModel();
    model.setName(Username);
    //model.setPassword(password); <-- want to remove the need for this
    UserModels = getUserModelManager().find(model);
```

Even though I know the data is there, my query returns nothing.

Can any one suggest why nothing is returning?

Any suggestion welcome.

Comment: We need to see what UserModelManager#find looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use HQL.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from UserModel where password = :password ");
query.setParameter("password", password);
List<UserModel> list = query.list();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm not sure that's the way I should do it.

A row is returned with I pass in user and password without the need to write any sql into my code..

I don't understand why the code doesn't return the row based on the username..

Comment: First of all this is not SQL, but HQL. And this is the way to query data by attribute. Second I don't know what is getUserModelManager.

Comment: I rebuilt and redeployed my code and it worked.. A row was returned by only passing in a username.

Comment: good, but it's hard to answer this questions without knowing what getUserModelManager is.